# A typeclass instance that needs configuration data. What are my options?

Tags: haskell, configuration, yesod, typeclass

Using yesod and persistent, I made what I think is a handy type to handle Markdown data:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Utils.MarkdownText where

import Prelude
import Data.Text.Lazy
import Data.Text as T
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sql
import Text.Blaze
import Text.Markdown

newtype MarkdownText = MarkdownText { rawMarkdown :: T.Text }

instance PersistField MarkdownText  where
    toPersistValue = PersistText . rawMarkdown

    fromPersistValue (PersistText val) = Right $ MarkdownText { rawMarkdown = val }
    fromPersistValue _ = Left "invalid type"

instance PersistFieldSql MarkdownText where
    sqlType _ = SqlString

instance ToMarkup MarkdownText where
    toMarkup = (markdown def) . fromStrict . rawMarkdown

    preEscapedToMarkup = toMarkup . rawMarkdown
```

You may notice in the `ToMarkup` instance I use `def` to get markdown parameters. If I would like to change these settings, and not have it hardcoded in this module, what are my options?

I have considered the option of making `MarkdownText` take the settings information as a parameter, but what other options are there (if any)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to simplify the problem so that we only need core libraries. We want to change how we `Show` a `MarkdownText` based on some `ExampleSettings` that contain a `prefix` and a `suffix`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Text as T
import Data.Monoid
import Data.String

newtype MarkdownText = MarkdownText { rawMarkdown :: T.Text}

instance IsString MarkdownText where
    fromString = MarkdownText . fromString

data ExampleSettings = ExampleSettings { prefix :: T.Text, suffix :: T.Text }
def = ExampleSettings "" ""

emphasise = def { prefix = "*", suffix = "*" }

showWithSettings :: ExampleSettings -> T.Text -> String
showWithSettings set = show . (\x -> prefix set <> x <> suffix set)

instance Show MarkdownText where
    show = showWithSettings def . rawMarkdown

main = print $ MarkdownText "Hello World"
```

There are a number of options for how to solve this problem, first at the value level, then at the type level, and finally globally at the type level.

#### Add a field

We have a few options for how we can proceed. The simplest option is to add the setting at the value level. We'll wrap up the settings with the `MarkdownText`.

```
data ConfiguredMarkdownText = ConfiguredMarkdownText {
                                  markdownText :: MarkdownText,
                                  settings :: ExampleSettings }

instance Show ConfiguredMarkdownText where
    show t = showWithSettings (settings t) (rawMarkdown . markdownText $ t)

main = print $ ConfiguredMarkdownText "Hello World" emphasise
```

For convenience, we added an `IsString` instance for `MarkdownText` in the first section.

#### Add a type parameter

We could carry the extra data we need around at the type level instead of at the value level. We add a type parameter to `MarkdownText` to indicate which settings to use.

```
newtype MarkdownText s = MarkdownText { rawMarkdown :: T.Text}
```

We make types to represent the possible settings

```
data Def = Def
data Emphasise = Emphasise
```

We can add a type class for types that determine settings, and instances for the possible settings.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class Setting v k | k -> v where
    setting :: proxy k -> v

instance Setting ExampleSettings Def where
    setting _ = def

instance Setting ExampleSettings Emphasise where
    setting _ = emphasise
```

We can `Show` any `MarkdownText s` as long as `s` provides the `Setting`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

instance (Setting ExampleSettings s) => Show (MarkdownText s) where
    show t = showWithSettings (setting t) (rawMarkdown t)

main = print ("Hello World" :: MarkdownText Emphasise)
```

`MarkdownText :: * -> *` requires a slightly different `IsString` instance.

```
instance IsString (MarkdownText s) where
    fromString = MarkdownText . fromString
```

#### Reflect the value from a type parameter

The [reflection](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection) package provides a way to temporarily associate a value with a type. This lets us do the same thing as in the previous example, but without needing to make types of our own to represent the settings.

```
import Data.Reflection
```

We start by adding an extra type parameter to `MarkdownText`, the same as in the previous section.

```
newtype MarkdownText s = MarkdownText { rawMarkdown :: T.Text}
```

The reflection package defines a class, [`Reifies`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-1.5.1.1/docs/Data-Reflection.html#t:Reifies), that is almost identical to the `Setting` class we made for the previous section. This lets us jump straight to defining the `Show` instance.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

instance (Reifies s ExampleSettings) => Show (MarkdownText s) where
    show t = showWithSettings (reflect t) (rawMarkdown t)
```

We'll define a little convenience function to tag the type parameter of `MarkdownText`s

```
markdownText :: proxy s -> T.Text -> MarkdownText s
markdownText _ = MarkdownText
```

and complete the example of setting the `ExampleSettings` to be used when showing a `MarkdownText`. We provide the reified value with [`reify :: a -> (forall s. Reifies s a => Proxy s -> r) -> r`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-1.5.1.1/docs/Data-Reflection.html#v:reify), which passes back a proxy for the type the value has been reified to.

```
main = reify emphasise (\p -> print (markdownText p "Hello World"))
```

This has an advantage over the simpler version from the next section; multiple settings can be used for `MarkdownText`s with different type parameters.

```
main = reify emphasise $ \p1 ->
       reify def $ \p2 ->
       do
           print (markdownText p1 "Hello World")
           print (markdownText p2 "Goodbye")
```

#### Reflect a global configuration

The reflection package also defines a simpler class, [`Given`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-1.5.1.1/docs/Data-Reflection.html#t:Given). It's defined as  `class Given a where given :: a`. It represents values that can be determined from the type of the value itself. This allows us to provide a single global configuration value for a specific type, like `ExampleSettings`. We can jump straight to writing the show instance for `MarkdownText`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

instance (Given ExampleSettings) => Show (MarkdownText) where
    show = showWithSettings given . rawMarkdown
```

We provide the `given` `ExampleSettings` with [`give :: a -> (Given a => r) -> r`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflection-1.5.1.1/docs/Data-Reflection.html#v:give).

```
main = give emphasise $ print (MarkdownText "Hello World")
```

Comment: I can see from the warnings in the documentation that `Given` is some sort of horrible hack, but I can't understand what it actually does. The type of `give` makes no sense to me. Could you try to explain it?

Comment: I had some issues using Given (I tried that first, since it seemed the nicest wrt minimal changes necessary). The documentation speaks of instances in scope, which is not clear to me. Especially how/if that limits what can be done with it and where it can be used.